# Python 2.7: How would I go about creating a dictionary that maps the first n numbers to their respective squares or cubes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I currently have this piece of code (for squares), but it doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
    for n in range(len(dict)): 
       if n == 0:
          pass
       else:
          squares = (n*n)
    dict[n]=squares
```

Comment: your indent for the `dict[n] = squares` line is wrong

Answer (score 4):

The parameter of `range()` should be `n`, because the dictionary is probably empty when you begin.
Also, `dict` is a builtin type in python and you shouldn't name your variables this way.

```
squares = {i:i*i for i in xrange(n)}
```

Comment: he wants a dictionary mapping the original number to its square, not a separate list

Comment: @RNar this is dictionary comprehension doing exactly what you/OP described. no lists are involved.

Comment: sorry, didnt realize the `i:i*i`. thought it was just a list comprehension

Answer (score 2):

```
dict={}
for i in range(n):
    dict[i]=i*i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
squares={}

for r in range(int(n) + 1):
     if r == 0:
         pass;
     else:
         squares[r] = (r * r)
```

This code will create a dictionary, look through all of the values up to n, and add the square tot he dictionary at index "r"! This code fulfills all of the requirements you asked for! Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear from the question whether `dict` already contains values. Also I'm not sure why you're skipping `n==0`.

Assuming you have a list `dict` with a certain length, your code should work for all values except the first (which you're skipping), except that your last line is not indented, so it's not run inside the loop. This should do it:

```
for n in range(len(dict)): 
    dict[n]=n*n
```

Anyway I recommend a list comprehension to do this:

```
dict = [n*n for n in len(dict)]
```

Comment: Why not a dictionary comprehension?  `squares = {n:n*n for n in range(100)}`  BTW, you copied a couple of the OP's mistakes.  `dict` doesn't have a length before it's constructed, and you shouldn't overwrite the built-in 'dict'. :-)